# A way to order roles

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm looking for a way to order my roles. As a ranking of roles.

Let me explain, my users can create Roles. A role can be superior than another one, and I'm looking for a way to do that.

A user can create a new user, and choose the role he'll have, and I want to restrict certain roles. A moderator can't create an admin or moderator, but only a normal user.

Here is my Role model :

```
class Role extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attribute that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description'
    ];

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Permissions:class);
    }
}
```

Each role has its permissions.

Do you have any idea for doing this ?

Comment: There are some packages for Laravel out there to handle roles https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+roles&oq=laravel+roles . Maybe take a look at how they have done or you could maybe use one of them and save some time? I looked at one of them which has level functionality. Then you could verify that the user can only create users with permissions on the same level or lower.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look! I made it myself but I think it's not very stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles & Permissions are a common feature added to Laravel applications and I have found that there are some really good libraries out there to pick from such as `laravel-permission` by the Spatie guys (https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/)

Even if you don't pick an existing library, the principles will be the same.

1. A `Role` will have many `Permission`'s
2. Each `Permission` will grant access to an action and/or area
3. A check is made when an action is performed to see if the currently authenticated user has permission (usually by middleware)

So if you want to restrict the ability of a "Moderator" to create "Admin" or "Moderator" users, create a permission for it like "can create admin users" and assign that only to the "Admin" user.

So you aren't really "ordering" or "ranking" your `Role`s, think of it more like a role is just a collection of `Permission`s

Comment: Thank you! I'll use that